# Unit test on legacy code, object creation

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I am adding unit tests to an existing application.  The class relationship is like this:

```
class TopClass creates class A and B and common class AB;
class A creates class A1, A2, A3, A4 and AB;
class B creates class B1 and AB;
```

I am told to pass all depended objects (as interface) when creating the top level object in order to do dependency injection. So class Constructors need to be changed as this:

```
TopClass(A a, A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3, A4 a4, AB ab, B b, B1 b1)
A(A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3, A4 a4, AB ab)
B(B1 b1, AB ab)
```

Is it the right/good way?  Is there a way that no need to create all objects at the beginning of the application?

Comment: One small note: don't just mechanically invert the dependency of every class that's used internally. There's a distinction called [peers vs. internals](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/growing-object-oriented-software/U_8PsEOwT5k): if some object is a peer it's okay to ask for the dependency, for example through constructor injection. If an object is an "internal" implementation detail that does not use anything that makes your code hard to test, you might decide it's not worth injecting and just keep on creating it in the TopClass itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not a good way.

If possible, you should only have to pass in **interface** A and **interface** B

```
TopClass(A a, B b)
```

This way unit tests for `TopClass` only worry about its direct dependencies and not dependencies of dependencies.  This will also let you mock out implementations of `A` and `B` in your tests.

Then for tests of `A`you might have a constructor that passes in A1, A2 etc but `TopClass` shouldn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, that's where you start, but it's not necessarily a good ending point. TopClass should care only about (interfaces of) `A`, `B`, and `AB`. The implementations and dependencies of those objects are not relevant to TopClass. This also means that mocking TopClass should be very simple: You need a mock A, a mock B, and a mock AB, and you can pass those in directly.

How do you create an `A` without caring about `A`'s dependencies? Instead of an `A` instance, receive a `Provider<A>`, where [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) is Java's built-in no-argument factory interface.

At that point, your constructors look as follows:

```
TopClass(A a, B b, AB ab)
A(A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3, A4 a4, AB ab)
B(B1 b1, AB ab)
```

Where any of those types could be replaced with a `Provider<Type>` if you want to delay creation until you need it, or if you need more than one.

---

"But wait!" I hear you cry. "Doesn't that mean I have to make a complicated series of boilerplate Providers in order to hide the implementation/dependency details from TopClass?" *Yes, it does, and you can do that manually--or you can use a dependency injection framework like Spring, Guice, or Dagger.*

A manual one would look something like this:

```
public class EntryPoint() {
  AB ab = new AB();

  Provider<TopClass> provideTopClass() {
    return new Provider<TopClass>() {
      @Override public TopClass get() {
        return new TopClass(provideA().get(), provideB().get(), provideAB().get());
      }
    };
  }

  Provider<A> provideA() {
    return new Provider<AB>() {
      @Override public AB get() {
        return new A(provideA1().get(), provideA2.get(), ...);
      }
    };
  }

  Provider<AB> provideAB() {
    return new Provider<AB>() {
      @Override public AB get() {
        return ab;   // always reuse the same instance if you'd like
      }
    };
  }

  // and so forth
}
```

There, you've just extracted all of the creation and wiring into one class, which Guice can emulate at run-time and which Dagger can generate directly at compile-time. You'll need to work with your team to choose a framework you want, or start manually, but overall this should provide a lot of rewards in making an easy-to-assemble and easy-to-test application.

Comment: About the boilerplate provider, is the purpose of using provider class to put all object creation in one class? Is there any other benefits I am not aware of?

Comment: The purpose isn't to put the object creation into _one class_, the purpose is to _get it separate from classes containing actual business logic_. It could be actually implemented as one class or several, and could be handwritten or auto-generated, but is required for any DI/IoC solution (including dkatzel's solution above) to avoid the explicit constructors like yours in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the instances in this order:

```
AB ab = new AB();//and so on for all classes wihtout dependencies like a1, a2, ..., b1
A a = new A(a1, a2, a3, a4, ab)
B b = new B(b1, ab)
TopClass(a, b, ab)
```

But as you say, that `TopClass` creates instances of those classes, that is the actual problem. it should expect instances, not create them.
Maybe this way it doesn't even need the ab parameter if it only uses it for creating A and B.

Using some Dependency Injection Framework/Library can be one way of taking a lot of boilerplate away from the developer, but its costs like

- efford for changing code to make it work in application and tests
- runtime performance (depending on the framework)

should be considered.